# Frontpage products layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, products, product-list, grid-layout

So i placed this block of code in the Hompage CMS.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

It works, but the product layout on the front page, makes some holes in the layout. 
Can i change it? and maybe add a third column?

[image]

More zommed out

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is some basic css you need to modify or add.

The template - as you can see from your widget code is /your_theme/catalog/product/list.phtml (if it exists, else it will use a fallback).

So now you need to define some new css to modify the list on the front page, but not on the category view. In 1.9.1 you should have a body class of 'cms-home' or similar (better check yourself), so then just use that prior to your style definitions to only apply it to your front cms page.

The classes may vary depending on your theme, but as  basic guide ...

```
.cms-home .grid-products-list li { list-style: none; margin: 10px 5px; float: left;}
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with php. (planing on learning some due to Magento)
I've found the file, where do i add the CSS to? a seperate file?

Comment: Depending on your theme, it should be located in skin/frontend/THEMEBASE/THEMENAME/css/styles.css - and no php needs to be edited. This is css - cascading style sheet. See this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/280/understanding_magento_css

Answer (score 1):

open catalog/product/list.phtml
change

```
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
```

or add columnCount="4" to the end of your line

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="21" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" columnCount="4"}}
```

Comment: This will also change the column count in the Category view, which can be defined in the admin backend. From the screen grabs above it looks as if he already has 3 columns, just the margin / padding of each list item is too wide, so that no 3 fit into 1 row.

Comment: I don't think so he asked to add 3rd column, and yes I do agree with you changing list.phtml will reflect on the cataloge page but he can use the second option or chnage list.phtml to home-page-list.phtml

Comment: in the screen above it is 3 products - 3 products - one products ( Magento default behavior ) @Nickcap can you please confirm

Comment: It show 2 products - 1 product - 2 products - 1 product - 1 product. It dosn't do anything when i add columnCount="4".

Comment: I tried adding chaning the php like you showed, and i kind of worked, this is the result:
[screenshot](http://puu.sh/glPKG/8222cda85f.jpg).

Comment: it is working now all you need to do is to change the style: use this .products-grid li.item {
    margin-right: 1.36986%;
    width: 23.9726%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.products-grid li:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}